# The product of two positive definite matrices has real and positive eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Given two real positive definite (and therefore, symmetric) matrices $A$ and $B$, are all the eigenvalues of $AB$ real and positive?

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties) says $AB$ is positive definite if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite and commute, but I don't need $AB$ to be symmetric.
- Between the lines of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326944/evaluating-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices) the asking user somehow prove that yes, "the eigenvalues of $AB$  are hence real and strictly positive" but I couldn't understand if that is confirmed in the answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If we call $B^{1/2}$ the symmetric matrix such that $B^{1/2}B^{1/2}=B$ (i.e. the standard square root of a positive definite matrix) then 
$$
AB=AB^{1/2}B^{1/2}=B^{-1/2}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})B^{1/2},
$$
that is $AB$ is similar to the positive definite matrix $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$, sharing all eigenvalues. It makes the eigenvalues of $AB$ be positive.

Comment: Thank you @A.G. ! I suppose we can also say that they're real since $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is positive definite. Correct?
Anyway I can't see why $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is positive definite...

Comment: $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ has real eigenvalues as it is symmetric.

Comment: Sure. $B^{1/2}$ is real. Look, the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real, thus the eigenvectors too. So the Jordan form is real $B=U\Sigma U^T$ with $\Sigma$ being diagonal positive and $U$ orthogonal. Then construct $B^{1/2}$ as $U\Sigma^{1/2}U^T$.

Comment: By definition $x^TB^{1/2}AB^{1/2}x=z^TAz>0$ for $z=B^{1/2}x\ne 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x\ne 0$. Thus positive definite.

Comment: @A.G. Ok I think I got it! Since $B$ is positive definite, its square root is positive definite as well ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties)). Since the product $MNM$ is positive definite if both $M$ and $N$ are positive definite ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties)), then $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is positive definite

Comment: @user3498429 Right. One can say even stronger that $MNM$ is positive definite for *all* symmetric non-singular $M$ as long as $N$ is positive definite. Just by definition (in my previous post).

Comment: @A.G.  your penultimate explanation was perfectly clear, I haven't seen before commenting. Thank you again!

Comment: @user3498429 You are welcome!

Comment: Does the original problem statement still hold if the matrices are merely self-adjoint but not necessarily positive?  In this case, we can't really take the square root, but is it fundamentally a different situation?

Comment: @keej Positivity of eigenvalues for $AB$ is clearly out of question (for example, $A=I$, $B=-I$). To see that eigenvalues may be non-real: try $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Did you assumed $A$ and $B$ are commutative in your argument? 
Because otherwise $AB$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @YMA No, I didn't. OP says that $AB$ does not need to be symmetric.