# Given $A,B$ self adjoint matrices in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ with positive real eigenvalues. Show that the eigenvalues of $AB$ are positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given $A,B$ self adjoint matrices in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ with positive real eigenvalues. Show that the eigenvalues of $AB$ are positive.

I think this can either be done by showing that $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously diagonolized (not 100% sure) or maybe showing that $<ABv,v>$ is bigger than $0$ somehow?

Edit: I dont think this question is the same as the possoble duplicate sonce mine is not about real matrices specifically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The product of two positive definite matrices has real and positive eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365079/the-product-of-two-positive-definite-matrices-has-real-and-positive-eigenvalues)

Comment: What does you mean by *positive*, $\geq 0$ or $>0$?

Comment: @Daw I dont think its a duplicate since that question is about real matrices specifically

Comment: @C.ding I mean $>0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AB$ is similar to $A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2}=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, which is positive definite.

Comment: What does $A^{1/2}$ mean? Sqrt? There must be some properties about Positive definte matrices which I don't know about :/

Comment: @Jason It's the unique positive definite square root of $A$.

Comment: Hmm we have not learnt that. I'll have to look it up thanks! If by any chance you know of a more elementary method to show this I'd love to hear it

Comment: @Jason You may use a Cholesky decomposition instead. Let $A=LL^\ast$ be the Cholesky decomposition of $A$. Then $AB$ is similar to $L^{-1}(AB)L=L^\ast BL$, which again is positive definite.

Comment: @Jason : If $A$ is selfadjoint it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_N \}$. If $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_N$ are the corresponding eigenvalues, and if these are positive, then $A^{1/2}x=\sum_{k=1}^N \lambda_k^{1/2}\langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$ is a positive square root of $A$, which is all you need to justify user1551's argument.

Comment: @DisintegrationByParts Thanks! That makes sense, I understand this answer now.